# using more than one JSON Api URLs

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

I have a page with pictures and when you click a picture it directs you to detail page with bigger version of the picture and its details.

I have 2 JSON api URLs. I need to use them both, one is for the main page and detail page, and the other is for only detail page.

Like that : on the main page`(index.js)`, I use `title` and `image` attributes of the first URL, and on the detail page`(pic.js)` I should use `image` and `content` attribute from the first URL and again `content` attribute from the second URL.

How can I do it? I can post my codes if needed.

Comment: are you looking for how to improve the api/overall design or how to best use it in its current state?

Comment: I'm trying to find out how. Right now I'm only using the first URL. So my detail page only has image and first URL's content  attributes. I need to add the second.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: create two models!

If you have additional data for your detail page you add another model with a 1:1 relationship:

*models/picture.js*

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  image: DS.attr('string'),
  details: DS.belongsTo('picture-detail'),
});
```

*models/picture-details*

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  content: DS.attr('string'),
  picture: DS.belongsTo('picture'),
});
```

Comment: then will I only call only "picture-details" in the details route? Should I also create a nested-route ?

Comment: also, where exactly should I write the other URL? I'm using return Ember.$.getJSON in the index with one url now.

Comment: If you use `ember-data` you should never call `Ember.$.getJSON` manually. Always call the store, and implement an adapter. There you may call `.getJSON` directly, but usually you don't have to.

Comment: Ok thanks but where and how am I gonna return two URL's ? I'm trying to do it in the application.js which I created as an adapter with Ember.$.getJSON but I can't

Comment: Create one adapter for each model. Don't call `.getJSON`, but override the `urlFor` functions.